# Booktabs Cell Coloring Overflow and Position Bias

Tags: tables, color, booktabs, kerning

I want to fill `booktabs` table cells in a custom manner. I did two examples as below, one with kerning and the other is straight `booktabs` table. The first problem is in both tables, coloring that is not at the table border overflows up to the border of the next column (the red line in the image indicates this). The second problem is kerning macros (or whatever they are called), distracts the positioning of cell texts, as seen in the image. The texts are biased to bottom of the cell.

- How can I prevent overflowing in single cell coloring?
- How can I remove position bias? (Maybe this can be inherently fixed after finding a solution to the first question)

[image: Table Outpts]

```
\begin{table}[b!]
    \centering
    \caption{Kern'ed Table.}
    \label{tab:graphExplanation}
    %\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}
    \extrarowheight=\aboverulesep
    \addtolength{\extrarowheight}{\belowrulesep}
    \aboverulesep=0pt
    \belowrulesep=0pt
    \begin{tabular}{>{\kern-\tabcolsep}cccc<{\kern-\tabcolsep}} 
        \toprule
        
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{MulC1} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{MulC2}  \\
        \cmidrule(r){1-2} 
        \cmidrule(r){3-4}
        
        \textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2} & \textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2}  \\
        
        Cell & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} Cell & Cell & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Cell \\
        
        Cell &  \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Cell & Cell &  \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Cell \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\begin{table}[b!]
    \centering
    \caption{UnKern'ed Table.}
    \label{tab:graphExplanation}
    %\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.15}

    \begin{tabular}{@{}cccc@{}} 
        \toprule
        
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{MulC1} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{MulC2}  \\
        \cmidrule(r){1-2} 
        \cmidrule(r){3-4}
        
        \textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2} & \textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2}  \\
        
        Cell & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} Cell & Cell & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Cell \\
        
        Cell &  \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Cell & Cell &  \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Cell \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you shorten the right side of the gray boxes in the second column, its contents will look off centered.

Comment: What do you mean with `.texts are biased to bottom of the cell`?

Comment: @Bernard they are centered off to the bottom of the cell instead of being in the center. It is more obvious in the positioning of `MulC1` and `MulC2` texts in both tables.

Comment: @leandriis off centering also applies to the other cells, as in my comment above.

Comment: I can see that the contents in your first example are not centered vertically but off set more to the bottom of the cell. What I was referring to in my previour comment is the horizontal alignment. If you remove part of the gray background the contents of the colored cells appear aligned to the right instead of horizontally centered.

Comment: You can quite easily achieve an output such as the following:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJaif.png In this example, the contents are indeed centered vertically, solving your second issue. However, I did not use `booktabs`, thus there is a solid instead of a split line below the headers.

Comment: The off  centering to the bottom of the cell is due to \extrarowheight. If you really want to centre vertically, I sugest using the `cellspace` package instead: it ensures a minimal vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in a column.

Comment: @ErdemTuna  have a look at the excellent `nicematrix` package below in the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two examples using an empty column between the first two and the last two columns:

Instead of lines from the `booktabs` package, I used regular `\hline` and `\cline` commands. In order to symmetrically increase the row heights of the table, I either used the `cellspace` package or the corresponsing options from the `nicematrix` package.

[image]

You can of course change the spacing above and below the text, as well as left and right of the text in a cell to your liking. Adding `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}` will for example result in the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%%%%%%%%%% used in the first example %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[column=0]{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{4pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{\cellspacetoplimit}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%%%%%%%%%% used in the second example %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{nicematrix}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}



    \begin{tabular}{0c0c0l0c0c} 
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{0c}{MulC1} 
        && \multicolumn{02}{c}{MulC2}  \\
        \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5}
        
        \textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2} && \textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2}  \\
        
        Cell & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Cell && Cell & \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Cell \\
        
        Cell &  \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Cell && Cell &  \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}Cell \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    
\bigskip

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-top-limit = 5pt,cell-space-bottom-limit = 5pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{cclcc}[code-before =\cellcolor{lightgray}{3-2,3-5,4-2,4-5}]
\hline
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{MulC1} 
        && \multicolumn{2}{c}{MulC2}  \\
        \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5}
        
        \textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2} && \textbf{Col1} & \textbf{Col2}  \\
        
        Cell & Cell && Cell & Cell \\
        
        Cell &  Cell && Cell &  Cell \\
        \hline
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With the excellent `nicematrix` package there is no problem

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{lccc}
\CodeBefore
  \cellcolor{blue!30}{3-2,4-2,3-4,4-4}
\Body
  \toprule[2pt]
  \Block{1-2}{MulC1} && \Block{1-2}{MulC2} \\
  \cmidrule(l){1-2} \cmidrule(l){3-4}
  \RowStyle{\bfseries}
  Col1 & Col2 & Col1 & Col2 \\
  Cell & Cell & Cell & Cell \\
  Cell & Cell & Cell & Cell \\
  \bottomrule[2pt]
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @F.Pantigny thank you for the correction -- education for me

Answer (score 2):

Just guessing (to long for comment). Do you like to have the following table:

[image]

For it is using part of each table. Also are changed `\cmidrule`s:

```
\documentclass{article}          
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[b!]
    \centering
    \caption{Kern'ed Table.}
    \label{tab:graphExplanation}
\begin{tabular}{>{\kern-\tabcolsep}cccc }
    \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{MulC1}                   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{MulC2}         \\
    \cmidrule{1-2}
    \cmidrule(l){3-4}

\textbf{Col1}   & \textbf{Col2}             & \textbf{Col1} 
                                                    & \textbf{Col2}             \\
Cell            & \cellcolor{gray!50}{Cell} & Cell  & \cellcolor{gray!50}{Cell} \\
Cell            & \cellcolor{gray!50}{Cell} & Cell  & \cellcolor{gray!50}{Cell} \\
    \specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{2pt}
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Edit:

- content of last column is centered
- `bottomrule` is replaced by `\specialrule`

**Addendum:**
IN the case, that you like to add `\midrule` between column headers and table body, you can do this with `\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{2pt}{0pt}`:

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\kern-\tabcolsep}cccc }
    \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{MulC1}                   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{MulC2}         \\
    \cmidrule{1-2}
    \cmidrule(l){3-4}

\textbf{Col1}   & \textbf{Col2}             & \textbf{Col1}
                                                    & \textbf{Col2}             \\
    \specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{2pt}{0pt}
Cell            & \cellcolor{gray!50}{Cell} & Cell  & \cellcolor{gray!50}{Cell} \\
Cell            & \cellcolor{gray!50}{Cell} & Cell  & \cellcolor{gray!50}{Cell} \\
    \specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{2pt}
\end{tabular}
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: I actually wanted to completely fill a cell without any overflow and causing off centering

Comment: @ErdemTuna, do you like to remove gap at bottom line? It is easy to achieve by use special rule described in `booktabs` package, page 6. See edited answer!

Comment: When I add midrule between second and third, it doesn't fill whole cell. Is it possible to fix that?

Comment: @ErdemTuna, yes, with use of the special rule: `\specialrule{\lightrulewidth}{2pt}{0pt}`. I will add this as addendum to answer asap.